# Django - form with foreign key to model with gallery

Tags: python, django

I have models like this:

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    source = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True) #TODO: check the field type, correct if needed

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.pk

class News(models.Model):
    content = MartorField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    creation_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    publish_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    picture_id = models.ForeignKey('Picture', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
         verbose_name_plural = "News"

    def __str__(self):
         return "%s" % self.title
```

And I'm using `CreateView` and `UpdateView`. When I use `{{ form.as_p }}` I have a problem, because picker of image is showing only id - not image. I'm looking for some widget or workaround to fix this problem.